# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:"09/16/2014"

Tags: java

I want to store a date into mysql table and I am getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09/16/2014" . Can any body help me?

```
I have tried in this way:
String sdate = request.getParameter("startDate");
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date dateObj = format.parse(sdate);

and the formate of "startDate" will be always like "dd/MM/yyyy".
```

Comment: The format of the date you are trying to parse is MM/dd/yyyy:
use DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")

Comment: @maress no it is `MM/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
MM/dd/yyyy
```

instead of

```
dd-MM-yyyy
```

How to decide [Date Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

[image]

Eg:

```
 String date = "09/16/2014";
 DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
 Date dateObj;
  try {
      dateObj = format.parse(date);
      System.out.println(dateObj);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
try{
String sdate = request.getParameter("startDate");
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date dateObj = format.parse(sdate);
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For more in `SimpleDateFormat` visit [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, what you're really looking for is converting the format from one to another. That can be done with two `DateFormat`(s) like,

```
String sdate = "09/16/2014";// request.getParameter("startDate");
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
DateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date dateObj;
try {
    dateObj = format.parse(sdate);
    System.out.println(format2.format(dateObj));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is

```
16-09-2014
```